# Make text fit in div

Tags: html, css

I have been working on re-doing my fathers website that was created in the nineties (ugh) and I have been having trouble getting the text to fit inside of a div and align horizontally. I need the text to sit next to each other so they fit in the div. Here's the code for the page in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2hchg2q/)

**Example HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<body>
    <div> 
        <img id="header" src="http://www.salesprofessionalsinc.com/images/new%20logo.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="links">
        <div class="home">
            <a href="index.html"><span></span>Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="home">
            <a href="insidestaff.html"><span></span>Inside Staff</a>
        </div>
        <div class="home">
            <a href="mission.html"><span></span>Our Mission</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Example CSS**

```
div img#header{
    width: 50%;
    height: 15%;
    margin-left: 125px;
    margin-right: auto;
}center input#search{
    width: 300px;
    height: 45px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-top: 55px;
    font-size: 25px;
}center button#searchbutt{
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 65px;
    height: 30px;
}#searchbutt:hover{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
}#searchbutt{
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}#links{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}.home{
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    vertical-align: middle;
}.DL{
    width: 95;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
}.home a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
}.DL a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
}div center a#DLbutt{
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}div center a#DLbutt{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
}#download{
    padding-top: 30px;
}html{
     background-image: url("watermark.gif");
}.home a span{
     position:absolute; 
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     top:0;
     left: 0;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     line-height: normal;
}
```

I need the "Our Mission part" to be in the same div.

Comment: Why do you have the rule for `.home a span` which sits on top of the entire page?

Comment: Also, setting the line-height to match the height of your divs works only for vertically centering a single line of text. You could fix this easily by making the .home divs 90px wide instead of 80. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h2hchg2q/6/

Comment: have you consider adding * word-wrap: break-word;*? In the home class

Comment: I meant for the span to only take up the div it was in

Comment: don't use `line-height:40px` to control the padding just use it on `<a>` tag something like `padding: 20px`. AVOID using selectors like `button#searchbutt` when you define ID `#searchbutt` its already unique so no need to add the DOM element to it... this is bad practice use

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are asking for. You want the "Our Mission" to be in the button vertically. Just update with this code. And it should work. Let me know what you think.

```
.home{
   width: 80px;
   text-align: center;
   height: relative;
   background-color: white;
   color: black;
   padding-left: auto;
   padding-right: auto;
   display: inline-block;
   border: solid 1px black;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I changed the height.. height: relative;

Comment: `relative` isn't a valid value for `height`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the display to be `display: table-cell` for `div.home` and then remove the `line-height` you have set for these. This should automatically align the text for you.

```
div img#header {
    width: 50%;
    height: 15%;
    margin-left: 125px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#links {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.home {
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid 1px black;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.home a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/03syn1to/

Answer (score 0):

## Modern Web Components solution: `<fit-text>`

You can do this with the `<fit-text>` Web Component, see: https://fit-text.github.io

```html
<script src="https://fit-text.github.io/element.js"></script>

<style>
  fit-text {
    width:25vw;
    border:1px solid blue;
  }
</style>

<fit-text>Hello Cool<br>Web Component<br>World!</fit-text>
```